# Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the objects within my jQuery code.

I've nearly this:

```
var opts = {
  ul: $(this).find('.carousel'),
  li: ul.find('li')
}
```

`li` property gives an error `Cannot call method 'find' of undefined`

How can it be fixed?

Comment: are you missing a # or . in the selection (`$(this).find('carousel'),`)?

Comment: are you sure jquery is loaded? Are you sure that _this_ is defined? are you sure there is an html element nested in this that matches the carousel selector?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter what your selector is, you can't access a property of an object that you are declaring, while you are declaring it.

Why would `ul` be declared? You're making a property `ul` on your `opts` object.

## Ugly:

What you might want is:

```
var opts = {
    ul: $(this).find('.carousel')    
}
opts.li = opts.ul.find('li');
```

But if you don't actually need references to both groups then:

## Cleaner:

```
var opts = {
    li: $(this).find('.carousel li')    
}
```

is just as good.

## Cleanest:

You could also do:

```
var $carousel = $(this).find('.carousel');
var options = {
    carousel: $carousel,
    carouselItems: $carousel.find('li')
}
```

## Godawful, but you asked for it:

```
var CarouselOptions = (function () {
    var options = function (carousel) {
        this.carousel = $(carousel);
        this.carouselItems = this.carousel.find('li');
    };

    options.prototype.myOptionsFunction = function () {
        // Don't know what you want your object to do, but you wanted a prototype...
    };

    return options;
})();
var opts = new CarouselOptions($(this).find('.carousel'));
```

#### Also

(Be careful with what your `this` is, presumably you have more than one `.carousel` element on the page, and here you want the one that is within the target of an event.)

Comment: so, how can I fix it?

Comment: $(this).find('.carousel li')

Comment: Store the result of `$(this).find('.carousel')` outside of `var opts`. Then use it when you declare `opts`

Comment: this doesn't look clean. what about the prototype?

Comment: The prototype of what? Object?

Comment: `li: $(this).find('.carousel li')` - that's not cool, I use caching not to overuse the selectors

Comment: @Steve ok save yourself a millisecond in return for more code

Comment: I've seen the code like `opts.prototype.ul = something`, can you describe it in your answer?

Comment: Man, using an IIFE here is like using a katana for cutting bread.  A word to the wise, if you try something like that, you'll run into problems later on.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Meh, standard pattern for creating a class. He asked for shit with `prototype`.

Comment: `Cleanest` is definitely the way to go for an instance like this.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal thanks for the prototype! What about the myOptionsFunction, how can it be used outside the CarouselOptions (after var opts)? I got a strange result in log on this example http://jsfiddle.net/dFmKZ/

Comment: @Steve You do not, I repeat DO NOT, want to do that in this case! Unless you are going to have a whole lot of instances of `CarouselOptions`, but even then, trying to force JavaScript to be OOP is normally not a good idea. The prototype of a constructor contains functions and properties that are set (and can be modified on **ALL** instances of that constructor), so you access it like `opts.myOptionsFunction`, but it looks up the prototype chain to find it. If you change that function, it will change all other `CarouselOptions`. I strongly suggest you go for the "Cleanest" option.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is essentially saying that `$(this)` is undefined (or in other words, jQuery couldn't find this element).  Because you don't have any code other than the single object you are trying to set, I don't know what the actual value of `this` is.

What I would do is ensure that `this` is set to an element of some sort.  A simple `console.log(this)` should handle that.  If `this` isn't an HTML element, then that's your problem.  Either ensure you are inside of a jQuery event function like this:

```
$('#id').click(function() { 
    this === document.getElementById('id');  // true
});`
```

Or you can just drop the `$(this)`:

```
var opts = {};
opts.ul = $('.carousel'),
opts.li = opts.ul.find('li')
```

Comment: Actually, I think I'm talking out of my ass in this instance.

Comment: are you sure? @henomnomnominal says it won't work in the following way

Comment: Try it this way.  You can refer to opts.ul after you set it.

Comment: It wouldn't work that way because the way `this` is set.  I was thinking for some reason I was inside a function there, and `this` would be set to the object scope (which isn't true in this case).

Comment: The error isn't with `this` it's with `ul`. Also `$('.carousel')` is much more general than `$(this).find('.carousel')`, probably not what he wants.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal Ahh, it seems I misread his question then.  Durp.

Answer (score 0):

```
var that = $(this);
var opts = {
    ul: that.find('.carousel'),
    li: ul.find('li')
}
```

Comment: @Steve Sorry I misunderstood the context :)